# Como definir um tempo limite para uma requisição?

Tags: angularjs, http

Estou fazendo uma requisição `JSONP` para um webservice. Porém as vezes a requisição demora muito. Como estou mostrando para o usuário um status de carregamento, gostaria de abortar a requisição caso passe de 10 segundos.

Como é que eu defino um timeout para uma requisição em AngularJS?

Exemplo:

```
var url = "https://exemplo.com.br/" + $scope.consulta.cep + "/json/";

$http.get(url)
.then(function (response) {

   // faz o resto aqui
})
```

Comment: Viu cara, deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa levemente fora do contexto: você tá usando styleguide?

Comment: Vixe, o que é isso?

Comment: É um manual de boas práticas pra programar em Angular. Eu queria ter descoberto isso quando comecei a aprender: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só você colocar a configuração `timeout`:

```
$http.get(url, {timeout: 10000})...
```

Caso queira fazer com promessa:

```
var cancelar = $q.defer();

$http.get(url, {timeout: cancelar.promise})...

$timeout(cancelar.resolve, 10000);
```

Comment: Cara, você não vai acreditar. Não quer funcionar! Parece que é realmente simples, mas a treta trava aqui e não para mais.

Comment: Li sobre isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739988/abort-jsonp-request-angularjs. Parece que realmente, não tem como. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Ué, que esquisito, tenho quase certeza que eu já usei isso aí. Será que só dá esse problema pra `JSONP`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Dá pra tentar fazer com a promessa qualquer coisa. Se você quiser monto um exemplo

Comment: To achando que é. Vou fazer um teste. Ao invés de mandar a requisição via JSONP, eu vou fazer do servidor para o WS, e do Angular para o servidor.

Comment: Pode ser com promise também. Quanto mais melhor :p

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou atribuir o `timeout` no interceptor?

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('timeoutInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
         url = config.url; 
         if (url == "myUrl") { config.timeout = 10000; } 
        return config;
      }
    };
 });
```

#### No config...

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutInterceptor');
```

Comment: Hum... No interceptor esse timeout ficaria padrão pra todas requisições.

Comment: Caso você precise tratar essa condição apenas para uma request em especifico aplique o timeout apenas nela. Ex: var url = config.url;
 function(config) {
         if (url == "myUrl") {
             config.timeout = 10000;
        }
        return config;
      }